# pyspark how to map two rdd to do something?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two rdds as follows.

```
rdd1: {'f1':[2,3], 'f2':[3,4]}
rdd2: {'f1':[3,4], 'f2':[5,1]}
```

I want to calculate the two rdds aaccoding to their keys.

```
def do_something(value_list_1,value_list_2):
    result = calculate(value_list_1,value_list_2)
    return result
```

Here, the input of do_something is like `[2,3]` and `[3,4]` on key `f1`.

May be it should like:

```
union(rdd1.values(),rdd2.values()).map(lambda (value_list1,value_list2):do_something(value_list_1, value_list_2))
```

I'm new to spark, hope for help.

Comment: Could you please add info on columns in your rdds? Does "f1" and "f2" are keys in different columns, or this is all in one column?

Comment: "f1" and "f2" and in different columns.